# Looking for material for learning geospatial development in Java

Tags: java, references

I want to begin using Java for geospatial development. For the purpose of learning I am interested in suggestions on some books, web sites, etc. (i.e. reference materials) that would help me out.

**Note:** I am using JDk and am also looking for suggestions on what geospatial libraries are available in Java.

Comment: This other question http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/4204/162 lists java projects you may be interested in. See their websites for learning resources!

Comment: Links and help provided are the application in itself. I wanted know using some java library. pure java and JDk oriented with some library files of geospatial if any.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/).  This is a Java geospatial toolkit maintained through OsGeo.

Comment: See this tutorial: http://www.slideshare.net/jgarnett/geospatial-for-java

Answer (score 2):

If it's a book you want, there's

[image]

It's rather old though.  The [book's site](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jwo/jpss/) has lecture slides and code examples.

Aside from GeoTools, you might also want to check the [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm).

> The [JTS Topology Suite (JTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite) is an open source Java software library
>   that provides an object model for Euclidean planar linear geometry
>   together with a set of fundamental geometric functions. JTS is
>   primarily intended to be used as a core component of vector-based
>   geomatics software such as geographical information systems. It can
>   also be used as a general-purpose library providing algorithms in
>   computational geometry